# Eclipse: пакет вложить в другой пакет

Tags: java, eclipse

Вопрос достаточно элементарный, но все же как вложить внутрь пакета другие пакеты. `IDE - Eclipse`.
При создании пакета, указывая `<имя пакета>.<имя вложенного пакета>` создается не как вложенным пакетом, а в том же месте где и старый.

Comment: а что именно значит там же?

Comment: внутри проекта, а не внутри пакета

<Имя проекта>
      .<имя пакета>
      .<имя пакета>

Comment: пакет - это просто папка, потому закинь папка в папка

Comment: да и так папка находится внутри папки

Answer (score 4):

В меню настройки проводника проектов, не зависимо от выбранной перспективы можно установить иерархический стиль для пакетов проекта: 
[image: Как это выглядит]

Answer (score 2):

В Eclipse есть два варианта просмотра проекта: Java и Java EE Perspective. Вот если смотреть проект в JavaEE, то там и видно эту самую иерархию.

Comment: Java EE Perspective отсутствует, у меня стоит   
Eclipse Standard/SDK  
Version: Kepler Release  
Build id: 20130614-0229